# get the timestamp from microcontroller tm4c123 in c

Tags: c, time, microcontroller

I am working in a small project using a microcontroller TM4C123. So I want to send data from microntroller to another microcontroller in c. The Microcontroller TM4C123 has RTC-module. So I can get  time from that Microcontroller. But I do not know which method I should call to get the time. There is a header file time.h But I do know, which method I should use. I need the timestamp for my data.Any Idea?

Comment: You are effectively asking how to program a (the) microcontroller. Sorry, but that is far too broad. You should watch out for a tutorial and the basics.

Comment: no, I can program with microcontrollers in assembly or c. But this is the first time I am doing something like that

Comment: So you know what to do then. Too bad there are so many words in the reference manual.

Comment: I opened the file time.h.  I am trying to use a method from that file.

Comment: C does not have [methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)).

Comment: You need to find the address of the RTC module in the datasheet or header file for that chip.  Create a pointer with the address of the RTC module and read it.  You may have to poke some registers in the RTC to start it up.

Comment: @ Olaf     Sorry, I dealed more with Java and assembly. So we say functions for c;;;;)))))))))))

Comment: @Steve: Thank you,  I will look for the adress of the RTC module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I solved the problem like this:

```
int main(void){
    SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN);

   //enable the hibernation module
  SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_HIBERNATE);

  //SYSCTL_OSC_EXT32 is the rate of the clock supplied to the Hibernation
  HibernateEnableExpClk(SYSCTL_OSC_EXT32); 
  HibernateClockConfig(HIBERNATE_OSC_HIGHDRIVE);
  HibernateRTCDisable();

   //set the value to 0
   HibernateRTCSet(0);
   HibernateRTCEnable();

   //get starting values
   unsigned long long sec = HibernateRTCGet();
   unsigned int subsec =  HibernateRTCSSGet(); 

    while(1){

         sec= HibernateRTCGet();
         subsec=HibernateRTCSSGet() 

    }
 }
```

This piece of code shows, how to use Real-time-clock through Hibernation module.  The clock signal to the RTC is provided by an external 32.768-kHz oscillator. One should keep in mind that the RTC reset on power on.

Answer (score 0):

In the embedded world, we typically have to do everything by hand. It is uncommon for there to be pre-defined methods to use the peripheral without some additional framework. The microcontroller's peripherals (including the real time clock) are typically interfaced via registers.

The silicon vendor will usually provide some header files that map the addresses to variable/symbolic constant names so you can read/write them easily. You will then need to read the datasheet to determine what to read/write the registers to achieve the behavior you want.

You will most likely wish to setup your own timer functions such as init_timer and get_current_time_stamp which in turn access these registers appropriately. Best of luck.

Further, keep in mind that the microcontroller's RTC is not likely to be non-volatile. This means that it will reset on power up. Therefore you will need to come up with some battery scheme for it to keep track of time.